# How to check if an input value is equal to a number

Tags: javascript

How can I check if `bath` value is equal to a number and not any other kind of value? I tried using NaN but it hasn't worked.

```js
 if(bath != '') {
  var bath = 'there is this many bathrooms :'
  house['bathroom'] = square;
  bathRoom.innerHTML = bath + Bath; 
 }else{
  var bath = 'No Details Given';
  bathRoom.innerHTML = bath;

 }
```

Comment: please declare variables at top.

Comment: Have a look into the typeof operator

Comment: all variables are declared at the top im just changing the value of them

Answer (score 1):

There's a great writeup of how to do this on [Mozilla's JavaScript webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger):

> The Number.isInteger() method determines whether the passed value is
>   an integer.

So, you would use `Number.isInteger()` like this:

```
Number.isInteger(0);         // true
Number.isInteger(1);         // true
Number.isInteger(-100000);   // true

Number.isInteger(0.1);       // false
Number.isInteger(Math.PI);   // false

Number.isInteger(NaN);       // false
Number.isInteger(Infinity);  // false
Number.isInteger(-Infinity); // false
Number.isInteger('10');      // false
Number.isInteger(true);      // false
Number.isInteger(false);     // false
Number.isInteger([1]);       // false
```

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers on StackOverflow. See **Provide Contents for Links** in **[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**

Comment: @Toastrackenigma I updated the answer to include relevant code fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the type of the variable with `typeof` operator.

```
var a = 1
console.log(typeof a) // --> "number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so (with a custom version of your original code):

```
var bath;

// here bath takes value some way...
// it may be: from direct user input, server AJAX request, JS expression...

if (typeof bath === "number") {
    // bath is a number
} else{
    // bath is NOT a number
}
```